# how to put delay between animations in Loop

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Im using `loop` to run animation infinitely but i want to run animation with a delay each time. the `delay` inside the animation just runs in the first time and not for further animation running.

Code:

```
Animated.loop(
            Animated.timing(this.state.spinValue, {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 3000,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                delay: 2500
            })
        ).start()
```

what i want is to run animation, then wait 2500ms, then run again.

whats happening is animation first start takes 2500ms delay but further loop doesn't have that 2500ms delay

Comment: What about looping once in an interval of 2500ms ? Don't know if it's possible, just an idea

Answer (score 3):

I found there is sequence possible that allow you to do what you want. Here is [an example on expo](https://snack.expo.io/@gasshette/animated-loop) based on an existing template and on [this article](https://medium.com/@benjamintodts/react-natives-animated-loop-invoking-a-callback-whenever-an-iteration-finishes-1c3581d38d54), and here is the animation code :

```
Animated.loop(
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.delay(3000),
        Animated.timing(this.state.animated, {
          toValue: 1,
        })
      ])
    ).start();
```

Comment: It worked for me, but I needed to add a third animation in the sequence to reset it `toValue: 0` and `duration: 0`.